# Is it illegal to impersonate a civilian online?

Tags: florida

There is a public figure from Washington (let's call him John) that is up to no good. I, a Florida native, wish to compel John to append a bible verse to each of his social media account's descriptions in retribution. I've deduced his address and now know his name, relatives' names, and their Facebook accounts—all of which are publicly available but not widely associated with his public identity—but I can't find any of his contact information. I wish to ascertain this from his relatives. Would I be within my legal rights to create an account under his name and send this message to one of them: “Hi Auntie Jane! I can't seem to remember if I sent you my new phone number. Do you know which number you have in my contact? Thanks for the help .” With that number, I would then message John, inform him of the information I have access to, and compel him to add the bible verses. This feels mildly illegal, but all of the information is publicly accessible, and I do not intend to extract any monetary gain from him. What are your guys’ two cents?

Comment: So, there is no gain for you (other than personal satisfaction) and no harm for him (other than having wasted a few bytes of the internet)?

Comment: @doneal24 The purpose of the email was immaterial?

Comment: @Barmar As far as I know, the content of the emails was not presented to the court, however I think trolling for personal information such as the target's phone number would be a factor in deciding to bring charges.

Comment: @doneal24 I wonder if that's just in Delaware. Here in Florida, I could not find any equivalent laws.